# PowerShell ISE Help Window doesn't show Parameters

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

PowerShell ISE has a Help Window pop-up, but I cannot enable Parameters (and Description) from Settings - Help Sections. Which is very inconvenient because despite having quick access to this really "helpful" help I still always have to go to online help to see Parameters.

**Compare this:**
[image]

**To standard: `Get-Help Get-Member -Full` or [full online help](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx).**

The same issue persists with new [PowerShell ISE preview](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellISE-preview/5.1.1).
And the problem also appears when clicking Help in little GUI for any command in standard PowerShell (not ISE): for example, after running `Show-Command Get-Member` and pressing `?` button.

For info, I already updated help with `Update-Help`, so it's not the problem.

Is there a way to correct this via GUI or somehow programmatically using `$psISE`?

Comment: How do you access this "Help Window pop-up"? I'm unable to reproduce this using `Get-Help Get-Member -ShowWindow` (PS 5.0 Preview, Server 2012).

Comment: @beatcracker: In standard PowerShell console it works exactly as you have written `Get-Help Get-Member -ShowWindow` (or as I have mentioned `Show-Command Get-Member` and then click `?` button to open Help Window pop-up). In PowerShell ISE console you can type `Get-Member` and press `F1` immediately (or in GUI `View - Show Command Add-on` to enable `Commands` tab, and in `Commands` tab choose `Get-Member` and press `?` button).

Comment: Still can't reproduce :/ . Is this Win10 on your screenshots? Because AFAIK,  Win10 has bundled PS 5.0 and it's not entirely the same as downloadable installer for older OSes.

Comment: Yes, it is Windows 10 with bundled PS 5. Try to install newer versions, maybe [PowerShellISE-preview 5.1.1](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellISE-preview/5.1.1).

Comment: Yep, `ISE Preview` _is_ bugged!